# Text moving centered image in flexbox

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar i'm trying to create. It has text on the left and text on the right. In the middle is an image. I am using flexbox to create this navigation bar. I have the image centered and the texts on the left and right. However, every time I try to add spacing using margin or padding on the text, the image itself moves and is no longer centered.

**HTML**

```
<header>
  <div class="header_container">
    <ul class="nav_menu">
      <li class="nav_text">Support</li>
      <li class="nav_text">Forum</li>
      <li class="nav_text">Live Chat</li>
      <li class="header_logo">

      </li>
      <li class="auth_btns">Login</li>
      <li class="auth_btns">Sign Up</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.header_container{
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav_menu{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav_text{
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.header_logo{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
    background: url("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: 200px 60px;
}
```

I am trying to put a margin on .nav_text, but every time I do the logo image moves with it and doesn't become centered anymore. How can I fix this? Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cshkx48b/4/)

Comment: It is aligning center only. I did not find any difference.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai If you change margins with nav_text, you will see the logo moving

Comment: given my answer below.

Comment: Can I rework your HTML for my solution?

Comment: @omukiguy Sure you can

Comment: Let me know what you think in comment.

Answer (score 0):

It is aligning in the center place only. May be you can see a little distraction, because of that last `.nav-item` also having the `margin-right`. For fixing this one, you have to apply `margin-right:0px` for the last nav-item element.

I have added one class and apply `margin-right:0px` for the last nav-item. Look at the following Snippet.

```css
header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.header_container{
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav_menu{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav_text{
  margin-right:30px;
}
.no-margin {
  margin-right:0px;
}

.header_logo{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
    background: url("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: 200px 60px;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="header_container">
            <ul class="nav_menu">
                <li class="nav_text">Support</li>
                <li class="nav_text">Forum</li>
                <li class="nav_text no-margin">Live Chat</li>
                <li class="header_logo">

                </li>
                <li class="auth_btns">Login</li>
                <li class="auth_btns">Sign Up</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
```

**UPDATE**

If you want your logo fixed on the center place of the header part, not worrying about the navigation links are touching or overwritten then apply the background image for the UL instead of `li` like below.

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.header_container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav_menu {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav_text {
  margin-right: 30px;
}    

.header_logo {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
}
ul.nav_menu {
  background: url("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: 200px 60px;
    background-position:center center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header_container">
    <ul class="nav_menu">
      <li class="nav_text">Support</li>
      <li class="nav_text">Forum</li>
      <li class="nav_text">Live Chat</li>
      <li class="header_logo">

      </li>
      <li class="auth_btns">Login</li>
      <li class="auth_btns">Sign Up</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

[**FIDDLE LINK**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lwabqcj6/7/)

Comment: This is still making the logo move. This is your solution here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lwabqcj6/ try to change the margin to 0 and then to 50, you will see how the logo doesn't become centered anymore.

Comment: so what you mean by center? it is center between the navigation links(Support, Forum, LiveChart) and sign Links(Login, Sign Up). do you mean the same?

Comment: I want it centered in the middle of the nav_menu div. But whenever I add margins, it slides the logo and makes it not centered in the middle

Answer (score 0):

```css
/*Default all ul to list none*/
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

/*Make all descendant containers flex with no wrap for large screens*/
header{
  display: flex;
  flex: no-wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  padding: 1px 20px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

/*Make li flex items. No flex basis attached so that the li give width*/
.nav_menu{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

/* Let all the remaining space be given to the image container. As the items on the lists in the sides increase, the logo container will reduce*/
.header_logo {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Restrict height alone and leave width flexible*/
.header_logo img {
  width: auto;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}


/*Make li flex items. No flex basis attached so that the li give width*/
.right_menu {
  display: flex;
}

/* li items give us the width of parent containers*/
.nav_menu li,
.right_menu li {
  padding: 0 2rem;
  flex: auto;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}


/*Make all descendant containers flex with wrap for mobile. We can incorporate order properties too*/
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  header{
    flex: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 520px) {
  .nav_menu,
  .right_menu {
    flex: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<!--Restructure the HTML so I can have more control on the different elements. Possibility of reordering the items on mobile-->
<header>
    <ul class="nav_menu">
      <li class="nav_text">Support</li>
      <li class="nav_text">Forum</li>
      <li class="nav_text">Live Chat</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="header_logo">
      <img class="" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
  </div>
  <ul class="right_menu">
      <li class="auth_btns">Login</li>
      <li class="auth_btns">Sign Up</li>
      <li class="auth_btns">Me Up</li>
  </ul>
</header>
```